# Cannot query field "books" on type Query Apollo client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

When running Apollo CLI command "apollo client:check --key="MyAPIKEYXX" --includes="./src/**/*.js"

```
✅Loading Apollo Project
✅Checking client: compatibility with service
```

**I got this error:**

```
Cannot query field "CreateBook" on type Mutation
Cannot query field "Books" on type Query


2 operations validated
2 failures
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

```
client.query(
  {
    query: gql`
       query Books{
        books {
          title
          author
        }
      }
    `,
  })
  .then((result) => console.log(result));

client.mutate(
  {
    mutation: gql`
    mutation CreatBook{
      createBook(input: 
      { title: "World"
      author: "De la ve"}){
       id
        title
        author
      }
    }
    `
  }
)
```

Comment: tested in playground?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, my type query and type mutation did not have the correct data type on the back end side....